# Retrieve a user's id and keep it as long as the session is active in jsf

Tags: session, jsf

I have a web application in jsf where I would retrieve the id of the user for reuse in other managedbeans.
Each user has a session that is created as soon as it is autehtification the data are stored in a Mysql DB. I would like to retrieve and keep the id of the user store as long as the session is active. Can you help me please?

this are my managedBean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ProfManagedBeans {

    private int idp;
    private String email, pwd;

    public HttpSession hs;

    public ProfManagedBeans() {
    }


    public int getIdp() {
        return idp;
    }

    public void setIdp(int id) {
        this.idp = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    public static PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    public static ResultSet rs = null;
    public String query="";
    public int dbid;
    public String dbemail, dbpwd;

    public String getDbemail() {
        return dbemail;
    }

    public String getDbpwd() {
        return dbpwd;
    }

    public void dbData(String uEmail){

        DbConnect.getConnection();
        query = "SELECT * FROM professeur where email='" + uEmail +"'";
        try {
            pstmt = DbConnect.conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                dbid = rs.getInt("id_pr");
                dbemail = rs.getString("email");
                dbpwd = rs.getString("pwd");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception " + e);
        }
    }

    public int getIdProf(){
        dbData(email);
        String ids = hs.getId();
        if(ids == hs.getId()){
            idp = dbid;
            return idp;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public String login(){
        dbData(email);
        if (email.equals(dbemail)==true&&pwd.equals(dbpwd)==true) {
                hs = Util.getSession();
                hs.setAttribute("email", dbemail);
                System.out.println(hs.getId());
                System.out.println(getIdProf());
                return "success.xhtml"; 
            } 
            else {
                FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage("Email error", "ERROR MSG");
                fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, fm);
                return "LoginProf.xhtml";
            }
        }

        public String logout() {
            hs.invalidate();
            return "/LoginProf.xhtml";
        } 
}

public class QuestionManagedBeans {

    private int id,id_pr;

    private String nomDesc, question, type;
    private String reponse;
    private double noteV, noteF;
    private String niveau, matiere,chapitre, explication;

    public static PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    public static ResultSet rs = null;
    public String query=""; 

    private ArrayList<Niveau> list ;

    public QuestionManagedBeans() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNomDesc() {
        return nomDesc;
    }

    public void setNomDesc(String nomDesc) {
        this.nomDesc = nomDesc;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getReponse() {
        return reponse;
    }

    public void setReponse(String reponse) {
        this.reponse = reponse;
    }

    public double getNoteV() {
        return noteV;
    }

    public void setNoteV(double noteV) {
        this.noteV = noteV;
    }

    public double getNoteF() {
        return noteF;
    }

    public void setNoteF(double noteF) {
        this.noteF = noteF;
    }

    public String getNiveau() {
        return niveau;
    }

    public void setNiveau(String niveau) {
        this.niveau = niveau;
    }

    public String getMatiere() {
        return matiere;
    }

    public void setMatiere(String matiere) {
        this.matiere = matiere;
    }

    public String getExplication() {
        return explication;
    }

    public String getChapitre() {
        return chapitre;
    }

    public void setChapitre(String chapitre) {
        this.chapitre = chapitre;
    }

    public void setExplication(String explication) {
        this.explication = explication;
    }

    public int getId_pr() {
        return id_pr;
    }

    public void setId_pr() {
        ProfManagedBeans p = new ProfManagedBeans();
        this.id_pr = p.getIdProf();
    }

    public boolean insertQuestion() throws SQLException {

       Question q = new Question(id,nomDesc, question, type,reponse,noteV, noteF,niveau, matiere, chapitre ,explication,id_pr);
       setNomDesc("");
       setQuestion("");
       setType("");
       setReponse("");
       setNoteV(0.0);
       setNoteF(0.0);
       setNiveau("");
       setMatiere("");
       setChapitre("");
       setExplication("");
       return new InsertDao().insertQuestionTF(q);
    }
}
```

I want to recover the id of the proffessor as soon as it is authenticated to be able to add it to the question table

In InsertDao.java

```
public boolean insertQuestionTF(Question qu) throws SQLException{

            DbConnect.getConnection();
            ProfManagedBeans p = new ProfManagedBeans();
            query ="INSERT INTO `question_tf` (`nomdesc`, `question`, `type`, `reponse`, `noteV`, `noteF`, `niveau`, `matiere`, `chapitre`, `explication`, `id_pr`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            pstmt = DbConnect.conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, qu.getNomDesc());
            pstmt.setString(2, qu.getQuestion());
            pstmt.setString(3, qu.getType());
            pstmt.setString(4, qu.getReponse());
            pstmt.setDouble(5, qu.getNoteV());
            pstmt.setDouble(6, qu.getNoteF());
            pstmt.setString(7, qu.getNiveau());
            pstmt.setString(8, qu.getMatiere());
            pstmt.setString(9, qu.getChapitre());
            pstmt.setString(10, qu.getExplication());
            pstmt.setInt(11, p.getIdProf()); 

            System.out.println("insert " + p.getIdProf());

            if (pstmt == null) {
                throw new SQLException();
            } else {
                return pstmt.executeUpdate() > 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show the code to us and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: @calexandre I modified my post adding the code and explaining where I am stuck thanks for helping

Comment: What is the actual problem? A session scoped bean is kept in memory

Comment: Can you help me get the id of the professor and put it in the url once it is authenticated and get this id back later in an other managedBean